# GlobalProtect (alternative) on Linux

Tags: debian, vpn, ldap

My new company gave me a Mac and I'm having a nasty time getting used to it. This post will likely irritate some of you, but please bare in mind I've been using Linux and Windows computers for years, with many keys added to muscle memory. Almost no-one knows less about using a Mac than I do. Anyway, they're not able to get me a Windows computer yet but seem open to me, once I have it, installing Linux on it, which I'd like to do. Most of my corporate apps are web driven, including email.

My biggest hurdle now is signing into a VPN. They're using this GlobalProtect. I downloaded a client and it actually runs, but does not work. The IT people suggest to sign in via LDAP. Assuming this is a workable thing, how would this work? I have the VPN host.

```
cat /etc/*release
DISTRIB_ID=LinuxMint
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.2
DISTRIB_CODENAME=uma
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Linux Mint 20.2 Uma"
NAME="Linux Mint"
```

Comment: The official client "runs but does not work". You might want to add some information to that passage. How does it not work: no routes, blocked traffic, login error,...?

Answer (score 0):

We've had some success in using [OpenConnect](https://www.infradead.org/openconnect/) with the GlobalProtect VPN, depending on if your network admins will allow it. Unless the [official GP-client](https://docs.paloaltonetworks.com/globalprotect/5-1/globalprotect-app-user-guide/globalprotect-app-for-linux/download-and-install-the-globalprotect-app-for-linux.html) works, which it does with (what we've tested) Fedora and Ubuntu.